# Is there a way to export output of "git branch -a" in a text file?

Tags: github, bitbucket

I would like to export output of git command `git branch -a` in a text file.

Comment: `git branch -a > output.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do:

```
git branch -a > result.txt
```

Comment: Thank you @Kristoffer for prompt reply

Comment: Can we enhance it and include author name in the output? Kristoffer